# USART RX Interrupt on an ARDUINO PRO MINI containing factory bootloader

Tags: bootloader, interrupt, arduino-pro-mini

Is it possible to use **RXC Interrupt vector** with the factory programmed **bootloader** still **existing** in the **arduino pro mini**?

I've written a simple echo program using RXC interrupt vector, the program prints "*READY*" on startup but as soon the chip receives the first character it goes into a **repetitive reset loop** i.e. I keep receiving `READY READY READY..` so on.

I've checked the program multiple times and I think its the bootloader, I think the bootloader has shifted the interrupt table to the boot section before executing the application. Is that so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

Once the bootloader transfers control to the main code (sketch) it may as well not exist any more. It does **not affect** the way the sketch runs.

---

> I've written a simple echo program using RXC interrupt vector ...

Please post this code. For you to print "READY" you are (presumably) using the Serial port, in which case the HardwareSerial interrupt vectors are being used. I don't know how you managed to take over those vectors. Seeing your code might answer that.

Comment: Hi Nick, I can't locate the code, its ancient now, sorry. I encountered this error while I was doing some quickie code. I had to use some arduino based libraries and I also required to use the Rx interrupt. As Far I remember, I wrote the usual __winavr__ style __ISR__ after importing __avr/interrupt.h__    That time, I think, my code was causing restarts and I kept getting READY READY READY. As you say, I did use the Serial port( Serial.print )and inside main() I printed READY. I think I should not have used the interrupt vector as it was already used by the arduino Serial port.